# Dynamics CRM 2016 : bug with extra buttons on the ribbon, how to fix it?

Tags: dynamics-crm

We have a strange bug on a Dynamics CRM 2016 (v8.1, on premise) : on a particular entity, no matter which form we use, when we try to use the extra buttons (hiding under the "..." button), the focus gets stuck on the dropdown menu and the first button on this menu start furiously blinking. We can't use those extra buttons, and we have to vehemently clicking on the form to get the focus back from the menu.

This bug does occur on only one entity, and exist on multiple browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE (although it behave a little bit differently on IE).

Do you have any idea where this could come from ? Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gNXS.png)

Comment: Nobody saw the same thing before ? My guess is, there is something wrong with the ribbon itself, we touched something on Ribbon Workbench that causes the problems, but we can't find what

Comment: If you did small changes on Ribbon for that entity, can you just revert it back and see if the issue disappears. I am guessing it can be some customization you did affects the behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was the cause of the problem. A function was used to determine if a button should appear or not, with an Enable Rule. However, this function contained a "Xrm.Page.ui.refreshRibbon()", which caused the ribbon to constantly refresh, and to continously call this function, etc etc.